# Visual Studio Code: .py option does not appear in the New File Menu with the Python Extension installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make the .py option appear in the VS Code New File Menu? It used to appear when having the Python extension installed, however, something changed.

[image: Please, see the menu image]

Answer (score 0):

It is useless, just type `name_file.py` and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Although the .py option never appeared on my machine, I've seen this problem several times. According to this [question](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/wjfxw4/new_file_selections_changed/), maybe downgrading the vscode version can solve the problem.

My suggestion is to add the following configuration to `settings,json` so your vscode will default each new file to a python file.

```json
    "files.defaultLanguage": "python"
```